# Is it possible to display a value based on presence of a cell border?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-import

We are looking at doing some data import. There is a very large complex sheet which has some items grouped together using borders around cells in one column. The only indication that the items are grouped is the fact the group is surrounded by a border. Items ungrouped have no left and right border on the cell (may have top and bottom border as items above and below maybe grouped). As an initial exercise we want to add a column that displays true if an item is grouped. So if there is a border display a value like one. Does anyone know if this possible?

Comment: Yes.  It's possible, but not with a built-in formula.  Give it a shot with VBA and we'll help when you get stuck.

Comment: Cool - just didn't know Excel enough to know if I was missing something. Will go off and see if I can do it in VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this custom VBA function:

```
Public Function GetBorder(ByVal Rng As Range, Idx As Integer) As Boolean
    GetBorder = Rng.Borders(Idx).LineStyle <> xlNone
End Function
```

It takes two arguments: cell and index of border (7=left, 8=bottom, 9=top, 10=right). Returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
Now if you want to get info about bottom border of cell `A1` you should:

```
=GetBorder(A1,8)
```

Comment: Any idea why if I put a border on the cell the result doesn't update without going into the formula cell and pressing return. Is there anyway to make it dynamic - I really have no need for it - just trying to improve my understanding

Comment: I guess no: border change on a cell is not a volatile event. You will have to press `F9` to recalculate.